# The usage of the word merely

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't know if a native speaker would say that but I will try to understand better the usage of this word.

Would you say

> I merely like something.

For example :

> I merely like pizza.

If it sounds natural  does this sentence connote either "you like pizza more than average" or "you like pizza less than average"

Comment: *Mere love* sounds contradictory. I *love* white pizza; I merely like ordinary red pizza.

Comment: @StoneyB I will edit my question then. When you say "  I merely like ordinary red pizza."  does this sentence have more or less strong effect than "I like ordinary red pizza"

Comment: I personally do not use *merely* for verbs. I use it for nouns: It's merely the author's opinion, after all; that's not so important." For verbs (liking food) I use *really* (for good) and, sometimes, *barely* (for not so good). In this case I can say, I *really* love this pizza. Instead of "barely" I would probably say 'I don't like this one very much.'

Answer (score 1):

> I merely like pizza.

This sounds like you're making a comparison -- "I love steak. I merely like pizza." In that context, using "merely" weakens the sentence, since it implies that you like other things more.

You could also use that sentence to make an excuse for your actions, like this:

> I'm not *trying* to eat quickly. I merely like pizza.

This usage is rare, and sounds overly dramatic. If you want to say something like this, use "just" instead:

> I'm not *trying* to eat quickly. I just like pizza.